# Getting "pointer being freed was not allocated" error with using a go shared lib in python

Tags: python-3.x, go, cgo

I keep on getting this error whenever I run the shared lib in pycharm:

```
Python(20566,0x116d67dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x5b6222f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(20566,0x116d67dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is my go code turned into a share lib:

```golang
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <errno.h>
import "C"


//export FreeCString
func FreeCString(ptr *C.char) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
}

//export TestString
func TestString() *C.char {
    return C.CString("Hello World")
}
```

Here is my py code:

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')

b = lib.TestString()
lib.FreeCString(b)
print(b)
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you're calling `print(b)` *after* freeing it, which is clearly a bad idea.

Probably more important, you never told Python about `lib.TestString`'s *return type*, so Python will make assumptions.  In particular:

> ```
> b = lib.TestString()
> ```

Since you never set `lib.TestString.restype`, Python believes the return type is plain `int`.  So `b` is set to a 32-bit `int` that results from throwing away 32 of the 64 bits of a 64-bit `c_void_p`.  (To fix this, [set the `restype` to `c_void_p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).  You should set the `argtypes` as well for all functions you call, although on the machine you're probably using, this probably won't matter.)

> ```
> lib.FreeCString(b)
> ```

This then calls, indirectly, `free((void *)(int)malloc(some_size))`.  As the pointer value has been damaged by the passage through `int`, the `free` call fails right then, stopping the program before you get to the bad use-after-free of the value that should have been stored in `b`.